# Dimple.js chart not working in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, github-pages, dimple.js

I have a dimple.js chart on my github page, https://jjchoi08.github.io/DSProj/simpsons_d3.html

In the html file, I have below two lines for d3 and dimple libraries as instructed in http://dimplejs.org/

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

The chart does not appear in my github page and it says something like, 
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.min.js”[Learn More] simpsons_d3.html
ReferenceError: dimple is not defined.

I found a work around where I go directly to https://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.min.js and allow access in Chrome, then it works. But I want other people to view this page. What should I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using external library,

instead of,

```
<script src="https://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

this works,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dimple/2.3.0/dimple.latest.min.js"></script>
```